# How to use Cosine Similarity with KD Trees in Scikit Learn or R?

Tags: python, r, scipy, scikit-learn, knn

Is there a way to use Cosine Similarity as distance metric with KD Trees in Python or R?
I tried giving `from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity` but it won't work.
Thanks!